# Interpretation of Eulerian numbers using the principle of inclusion-exclusion

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion, eulerian-numbers

Eulerian numbers, denoted $e_{n,k}$, are defined as the number of permutations of $[n]$={1,2,...,n} such that there are k "ascents". (For example, the permutation 23541 of [5] would have 3 ascents, 235, 4,  and 1)

How can the principle of inclusion exclusion be used so that:

$e_{n,k}=\sum_{i=0}^k(-1)^i {n+1 \choose i}(k-i)^n$

I will update this as I make progress.

We can think of the permutation as containing k groups of ascents.

So, say for $e_{n,2}$, the first value of the alternating sum is ${n+1 \choose 0}(2-0)^n=2^n$ This makes sense since we are placing n objects into 2 groups. Now we need to make up for the fact that each group must be an ascent.

Comment: There is such a proof on p. 8 of Bóna's [Combinatorics of Permutations](https://books.google.de/books?id=Op-nF-mBR7YC&lpg=PP1&ots=hS8gEKwrme&dq=http%3A%2F%2Fdx.doi.org%2F10.1201%2F9780203494370&lr&pg=PA8#v=onepage&q&f=false).